How to mock AsyncIterable paging sub-call from Jest mock?
I'm trying to mock an Azure SDK PagedAsyncIterableIterator, using Jest. The unit test fails on the ".byPage()" method call, with the error TypeError: this.storageManagementClient.localUsersOperations.list(...).byPage is not a function. The "list" mock works, but the list sub-call to "byPage" fails.
Here is my code:
async findAll(accountId: number): Promise<Array<SftpUserResponseDto>> {

    // ...
    // Get a list of Users from the Azure SFTP Blob Account
    const localUserPages = this.storageManagementClient.localUsersOperations
      .list(this.resourceGroup, this.storageAccount)
      .byPage();

    for await (const page of localUserPages) {
      // Do stuff with the list of Users on the page
    }
    // ...

And here is the unit test:
describe('SftpUsersService', () => {
 let mockStorageManagementClient: Partial<StorageManagementClient>;
 beforeEach(async () => {
    mockStorageManagementClient = {
      localUsersOperations: {
        delete: jest.fn(),
        list: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(sftpUsersMocks.listPage),
        createOrUpdate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(sftpUsersMocks.localUser1),
        get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(sftpUsersMocks.localUser1),
        listKeys: jest.fn(),
        regeneratePassword: jest.fn(),
      },
    };

  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        // ...
        {
          provide: StorageManagementClient,
          useValue: mockStorageManagementClient,
        },
      ],
    }).compile(); 
  };
  // ...
});
describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return a list of users', async () => {
      const accountId = sftpUsersMocks.account1.accountId;

      const users = await service.findAll(accountId);

      expect(users).toEqual(sftpUsersMocks.listResponse);
      expect(
        mockStorageManagementClient.localUsersOperations.list,
      ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(accountId);
    });
  });
});

In the mock, "list" is returning a mock called "listPage" which has the same structure as the real "list" response:
export class SftpUsersMocks {

  listPage: PagedAsyncIterableIterator<LocalUser, LocalUser[], PageSettings> = {
    byPage: jest.fun(),
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: jest.fn(),
    next: jest.fn(),
  };
};

I also tried mocking out the list.byPage() call explicitly, using this instead of the "list" above, but that didn't work either:
    mockStorageManagementClient = {
      localUsersOperations: {
        delete: jest.fn(),
        list: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
          byPage: jest.fn(),
        }),
      },
    };


Can anyone point me to where I went wrong?
